# Playsound() in C++ playing windows error sound, I have included winmm.lib

Tags: c++, playsound

I'm trying to use Playsound() in C++.

I've looked at everything but I always get the default windows error sound.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\Pokemon Game Stuff\\Programming\\Tests\\city simulator\\Sound.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

winmm.lib has been set up in linker settings. 
Full location and just filename has been tested. 
I'm Using Code::Blocks and compiling with C++ 14 standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`PlaySound()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680.aspx) documentation:

> SND_FILENAME
>   The `pszSound` parameter is a file name. **If the file cannot be found, the function plays the default sound** unless the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag is set.
>
> ...
>
> `PlaySound` searches the following directories for sound files: the current directory; the Windows directory; the Windows system directory; directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable; and the list of directories mapped in a network. If the function cannot find the specified sound and the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag is not specified, `PlaySound` uses the default system event sound instead. If the function can find neither the system default entry nor the default sound, it makes no sound and returns `FALSE`.

Double check that the file actually exists at the path you are specifying, and that the user that is running your app has permissions to access the file.